# Simperium - Files uploading but not syncing between devices

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, simperium

I stumbled across Simperium today whilst looking for an alternative to iCloud syncing my core data database.

I am impressed by its speed and visibility into the data transfers through the data browser, something which iCloud doesn't provide easily from my knowledge. I have followed the simpleToDo sample app and managed to get it working (the ipad version of the app had some errors which required fixing).

After being happy with how it seemed to work I decided to implement it in my app following the same steps as in the sample. I removed all of my icloud related code and re-implented the app delegate core-data code by virtually mirroring the code provided in the sample (only with slight alterations for my managed object model).

All seemed to go well in terms of creating a record in my app, I could see the change had been uploaded through the dashboard data browser tool of the website.

**My problem**

I have validated that data is being sent from both devices to the server, however, neither of these changes are showing up on the other device.

What am I missing? I cannot find anything in the code of the simpleToDo sample which seems to indicate a method which may be called to perform the update or refresh of the table views after receiving a notification of some sort.

Furthermore, I can't see any logs showing up to say that new records have been detected / added to queue or downloaded.

The last logs I have relating to Simperium are:

```
2012-12-30 21:00:46:772 myClients[745:907] Simperium authentication success!
2012-12-30 21:00:46.781 myClients[745:907] Reachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags
2012-12-30 21:00:46:782 myClients[745:907] Simperium starting network managers...
2012-12-30 21:00:49:514 myClients[745:907] Simperium finished processing index for Client
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am really looking forward to seeing this working for me as I believe it will be a good alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable more verbose logging on your Simperium instance:

```
simperium.verboseLoggingEnabled = YES;
```

That will help you confirm data is being received on each device. As you've already discovered, your app's web-based data browser can help you confirm data is being sent at all.

Beyond that, the sample you mentioned uses an `NSFetchedResultsController` which is a native class that automatically updates a `UITableView` as items are added, removed, and changed in Core Data. If you structure your app this way, you don't need to do anything else in order to update your table views.

If you need more complete control, or you have UI elements you want to update manually, you can use `SPBucketDelegate` to be notified when data changes. Each of your Entities has a bucket that you can retrieve from your Simperium instance. Then you can set the `SPBucketDelegate` on that bucket:

```
SPBucket *bucket = [simperium bucketForName:@"Todo"];
bucket.delegate = self;
```

The `self` instance will now have methods like `bucket:didChangeObjectForKey:forChangeType:` called when any object that is a Todo entity changes. You can see a complete list of these delegate methods in `SPBucket.h`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have enabled verbose logging and can now see the cause of the problem. I do use NSFetchedResultsControllers, however, the logging is returning the following error repeatedly "Simperium timeout, server didn't respond to GET code 504 (Client), retrying in 5 seconds...". Any idea, what this could be caused by?

Comment: The 504 is an expected log statement...a timeout occurs about once every 60 seconds and it's reconnecting. So the problem will be somewhere else. Any other clues in the log?